# How to configure Android AccessibilityService

Tags: android, android-service, accessibility

I am investigating Android `AccessibilityService` and wanted to see all possible types of events,
gestures and Key Events.

I am able to receive all `public void onAccessibilityEvent(final AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {}`

however my service nevers receives `protected boolean onGesture(int gestureId) {}` or 
`protected boolean onKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {}` calls.

When I enable my accessibility service in the accessibility settings I see the service connect OK

and I can see the service logging out from the `public void onAccessibilityEvent(final AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {}` method

What have I not configured? or configured incorrectly?

My Manifest file looks like this

```
<service
    android:name=".MyAccessibilityService"
    android:label="My Accessibility"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
        android:resource="@xml/accessibilityservice" />
</service>
```

The xml accessibilityservice contents are :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
    android:canRequestEnhancedWebAccessibility="true"
    android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true"
    android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:notificationTimeout="1000"
    android:packageNames="com.research.my.accessibility" />
```

The service AccessibilityServiceInfo is as follows:-

```
@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected();
    Log.d("TAG", "onServiceConnected");

    final AccessibilityServiceInfo accessibilityServiceInfo = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    accessibilityServiceInfo.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPES_ALL_MASK;
    accessibilityServiceInfo.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_ALL_MASK;
    accessibilityServiceInfo.packageNames = new String[] {"com.research.my.accessibility"};
    accessibilityServiceInfo.notificationTimeout = 1000;
    setServiceInfo(accessibilityServiceInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you need to change the flag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeContextClicked|typeViewClicked"
android:packageNames="com.example.andres.eventcapture"
android:accessibilityFlags="flagRequestFilterKeyEvents"
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
android:notificationTimeout="50"
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
android:settingsActivity=""
android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true"
/>
```

something like this.

or you can also try FLAG_REQUEST_TOUCH_EXPLORATION_MODE