# Google has stopped error dialog when using SpeechRecogniser Api

Tags: android

I am using Speech Recogniser in my app. If I am trying ok google and at the same time launching my app for speech recognition, then performing these steps repeatedly causing crash of google app. I am getting this an error dialog saying "Google has stopped" and log exception as :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: LocalEngine0
11-27 17:33:21.801 E/AndroidRuntime( 4490): Process: com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search, PID: 4490
11-27 17:33:21.801 E/AndroidRuntime( 4490): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unchecked exception running task: ThreadChanger: a.a(w, b, c)
11-27 17:33:21.801 E/AndroidRuntime( 4490):     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ba.setException(SourceFile:20)
11-27 17:33:21.801 E/AndroidRuntime( 4490):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
11-27 17:33:21.801 E/AndroidRuntime( 4490):     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ae.run(SourceFile:11)
11-27 17:33:21.801 E/AndroidRuntime( 4490):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
11-27 17:33:21.801 E/AndroidRuntime( 4490):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
11-27 17:33:21.801 E/AndroidRuntime( 4490):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
11-27 17:33:21.801 E/AndroidRuntime( 4490):     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:6)
11-27 17:33:21.801 E/AndroidRuntime( 4490): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
11-27 17:33:21.801 E/AndroidRuntime( 4490):     at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(SourceFile:33)
11-27 17:33:21.801 E/AndroidRuntime( 4490):     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.e.c.b.a(SourceFile:103)
11-27 17:33:21.801 E/AndroidRuntime( 4490):     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.c.a.a(SourceFile:31)
11-27 17:33:21.801 E/AndroidRuntime( 4490):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-27 17:33:21.801 E/AndroidRuntime( 4490):     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.bn.run(SourceFile:9)
11-27 17:33:21.801 E/AndroidRuntime( 4490):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
11-27 17:33:21.801 E/AndroidRuntime( 4490):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-27 17:33:21.801 E/AndroidRuntime( 4490):     ... 5 more
11-27 17:33:21.805 W/ActivityManager( 3327):   Force finishing activity com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.lockscreenentry.LockscreenEntryActivity
```

How can i overcome this error.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent false positives, **hotword detection** is disabled when a spoken feedback service is enabled.

add  `android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"`
configure the service using an XML file

```
 <accessibility-service
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeViewClicked|typeViewFocused"       
    android:packageNames="com.example.android.myFirstApp,com.example.android.mySecondApp"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"        
    android:notificationTimeout="100" 
    android:settingsActivity="com.example.android.apis.accessibility.TestBackActivity"          
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"/>
```

You can also refer these link [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296163/hotword-detection-disabled-with-accessibly-service),[two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43808450/how-to-configure-android-accessibilityservice)

Hope it will to you!!

Comment: I am not using any service for Speech recognisation, I am just using an activity with Speeh Recognition Api implemented, so not getting how to use what you have told.